# How to get profile picture with Microsoft.Graph SDK or User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have implemented authentication successfully with the quickstart project in Microsoft Azure, but now I'm stuck with getting the profile picture of a logged-in user.

I have tried using Microsoft.Graph SDK, but the `Photo` keep getting `null`.

```cs
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(ClientId)
    .WithTenantId(TenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

// Create an authentication provider.
ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
// Configure GraphServiceClient with provider.
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

I also tried getting a specific user with id and `.Select("Photo")` but the result is the same

```
var temp = await graphServiceClient.Users[user_id]
                    .Request()
                    .Select("Photo")
                    .GetAsync();
```

Maybe my implementation was wrong?

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `Select` query parameter searches for Photo property in user object, but there is no photo property. There is only photo relationships and it can be accessed using [`Expand` query parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter).

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma I change it to `Users[user_id].Request().Expand("Photo").GetAsync();` and got this error `Status Code: NotFound
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource could not be discovered.`

Comment: Please check if there is a mailbox present for this user as the photo comes from exchange workload.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma yes, because I tested with my own hotmail

Answer (score 1):

To get a photo as a stream you can use this code

```
using (var photoStream = await graphServiceClient.Users[user_id].Photo.Content
                               .Request()
                               .GetAsync())
{
    // your code       
}
```

Comment: Because Photo is `null` so I got this error `Status Code: NotFound
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource could not be discovered.`

Answer (score 1):

As I researched this same issue I constantly stumbled across this post. I figured I'd post my solution using the Graph API 5.6.0. It seems to have changed from what is above. In the code below `this.Me.Photo` is null and I believe even if it were not null it would only contain metadata about the image (width, height, etc.). To get the stream you need to build a ContentRequestBuilder and call GetAsync to get the image stream.

The way I did this was to create a Microsoft.Graph.Me.Photo.Value.ContentRequestBuilder based on the GraphServiceClient service I created in the app initialization. See Use [Graph API in a ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=graph-sdk-5) for details on creating the GraphServiceClient.

### The code:

#### UserInfo.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

using System.Security.Cryptography;

using PhotoContentRequestBuilder = Microsoft.Graph.Me.Photo.Value.ContentRequestBuilder;

namespace GdbRaiser.Pages;

[Authorize]
public partial class UserInfo
{
    [Inject]
    public GraphServiceClient? Client { get; set; }

    private User? Me { get; set; }

    public string? PhotoBytes { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _ = this.Client?.Me ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Client.Me must not be null");
        this.Me = await this.Client.Me.GetAsync();
        PhotoContentRequestBuilder photoRequest = new(new Dictionary<string, object>(), this.Client.RequestAdapter);
        using Stream? photo = await photoRequest.GetAsync();
        using StreamReader? reader = photo is null
            ? null
            : new StreamReader(new CryptoStream(photo, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read));
        this.PhotoBytes = reader is null
            ? null
            : await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

**Updated:** after a bit more research it's even easier. You can use the client directly:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _ = this.Client?.Me ?? throw new NullReferenceException("Client.Me must not be null");
        this.Me = await this.Client.Me.GetAsync();
        using Stream? photo = await this.Client.Me.Photo.Content.GetAsync();
        using StreamReader? reader = photo is null
            ? null
            : new StreamReader(new CryptoStream(photo, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read));
        this.PhotoBytes = reader is null
            ? null
            : await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
```

#### UserInfo.razor

```
@page "/Me"
@using System.Reflection;
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@code {
    public static readonly string? Route = typeof(UserInfo).GetCustomAttribute<RouteAttribute>(true)?.Template;
    public static readonly string Title = "Debug";
    public static readonly string[] Icons = { "fa fa-bug-slash" };
}
<PageTitle>@(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppTitle")) - @Title</PageTitle>
<h3>Hello @Me?.DisplayName</h3>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right"><label class="mr-2">Account Name:</label></td>
            <td>@(Me?.UserPrincipalName ?? "null")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right"><label class="mr-2">Phone:</label></td>
            <td>@(Me?.MobilePhone ?? "null")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right"><label class="mr-2">Phone:</label></td>
            <td>
                @if (PhotoBytes is null)
                {
                    @("null")
                }
                else
                {
                    <img src="data:image;base64,@PhotoBytes" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Bit too old for me to check since I moved to Go long ago, I will accept your answer if someone else also upvotes this